# PHP mail() function sending duplicate "From" headers

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP function that I have been using for a few years to send e-mail messages using the mail() function.  We recently converted our e-mail server over to our parent company and have been having some problems ever since.  We are now being required to use noreply@mycompany.com as the "from" address in the e-mail header.  OK, that is fine with me.  But we have been running into situations where some of these e-mails are not actually being received.  Our e-mail administrator has researched and discovered that the "from" address is being duplicated somehow in the e-mail header.  But that is NOT how I have coded it.  Here is the what we are using:

```
$to = "MyEmail@internet.com";
$subject = "TEST";
$message = "This is a test message";
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: noreply@mycompany.com\r\n";
$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

When the e-mail is received, the "from" address looks like this:

```
From: noreply@mycompany.com, noreply@mycompany.com
```

Any idea what could be causing this duplication?  It seems to be preventing delivery of the messages on some e-mail systems.

Comment: `mail()` isn't really appropriate for anything beyond some debugging messages.  Use something like SwiftMailer.

Comment: First i would try to remove this address from `$headers` variable and send email. Then check if sender was somehow added. If yes, then check `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` for definitions of sender.